# ArcSDE on SQL Server truncating fields even after changing Field Length

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server

I created a SQL Server Enterprise Geodatabase for our Fiber Network. Sometimes our strand descriptions get pretty long. I ran into an issue where some of the descriptions were getting cut off at 254 which is what I had set the length of the description field originally. I made sure everyone was out of the database and I changed the field length to a sufficent 1000 characters in SQL Management Studio.

The issue is that it will accept the additional characters UNTIL the user saves the edits, then it will truncate back down to 254 characters. I have been testing and testing and I compressed the database and I cannot figure out what the issue is.

Comment: Is this a versioned geodatabase? Did you change the Adds table schema as well?

Comment: We have not set up the versioning yet, everyone is working on the same features at the moment in different areas. I apologize I'm not 100% sure by what you mean when you say "Adds table schema"

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure this out.
There were multiple tables that contained the "countDisp" field. I also had to delete and recreate the "view" for that table. I did a query to find all the tables and views that had that field name and changed them all to 1000. Now when I save edits it is not truncating them any longer.